# Can you block reblogs from a specific Tumblr user you follow?

Tags: tumblr

Sometimes I'd like to follow an artist, but they tend to reblog like crazy and clutter my feed.

Is there any way to block their reblogs but keep the specific content they post visible?

Answer (score 1):

Some extensions such as [Tumblr Savior](https://bjornstar.com/tumblr-savior) and [New XKit](https://new-xkit-extension.tumblr.com/) can do similar things (e.g. blocking by tags), but I'm not clear if they can do *specifically* (I don't use Savior) what you're asking for in the absence of relevant tags to hook onto.